# 324 points, 54 games, 15 players

Tags: word-problem

The most points a player can accumulate over 54 games is 324. In each game, a player can score a 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 points. There's a total of 15 players in the league.

The 5 highest scoring players make the playoffs.

How do I calculate when a player is mathematically eliminated, meaning they can no longer score enough points to make the playoffs (5th place)

---

I'm not sure this is the right area to put this question...

Comment: Can a player get no points?  Can both players get 0 (or 1) points?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be a given player's score, let $y$ be the score of player who currently has the fifth highest score, and let $n$ be the number of games left. We should look at the scenario where the given player does as well as possible for the rest of the games and the player with the high score does as poorly as possible. In this scenario we need to have $x + 6n \geq y + 1n$ for the given player to still have a shot at winning, which can be cleaned up to be
$$
  x + 5n \geq y
$$

Comment: Does this account for the minimum score that the current-fifth-place player will score in those same remaining games? The queried player would need an additional point per game to cover this.

Comment: Correct. I hadn't noticed that the minimum score was not zero.