# Possibility of winning a poker league

Tags: probability

My friends and I play in a poker league and I am responsible for keeping records. First, a quick overview: Everyone pays a buy-in at the beginning of the year, and we play 11 monthly games. Each month, all players get points based on where they finish - a better finish means more points. At the end of the 11 games, the player with the most points wins the buy-in from the beginning of the year.

Recently, after sending out the results for our last game, I wondered how to calculate the possibility of any given player winning. Is it possible--knowing current point totals, points given per game, and games remaining--to estimate each player's probability of winning? For this example, I'm assuming all players are equally skilled, which is close enough to true.

I searched Stack Exchange and Google quite a bit, and while there are plenty of examples for calculating winning a tournament or making a flush or calculating EV, I couldn't find anything like this. I even found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674048/324-points-54-games-15-players) that talks about a similar scenario, but calculates something different.

Players: 9
Points per game (first place to last place): 11, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
Current point totals (player A to player I): 74, 68, 59, 51, 50, 50, 47, 45, 45

If it's easier to explain with fewer people, by all means. I imagine I can extrapolate from there. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Points assigned per game $=11+9+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=48$.  Points assigned so far $=74+68+59+51+50+50+47+45+45=489$.  This makes it look like $10.1875$ games have been played so far.  Please clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, how do you handle ties? For example, if you are playing 1 more game and player B wins 11 points while player A wins 5 points, both of the totals would be 79. Is that a "double win", a "half win" for each, or is there some tie-breaker?